# C++: What error in using STL vector

Tags: c++, linux, vector, stl

I was using the topcoder C++ compiler, and although this code just run fine in Linux gcc, the topcoder compiler gave this error:

```
your code did not compile:

errors compiling:

Your class or method was improperly declared: In function
   ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, 
   std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > _wrapper::thunk(std::string)’:

Your class or method was improperly declared:20034: 
error: conversion from ‘void’ to non-scalar type
‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, 
std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >’ requested
```

This is the code snippet where it is flagging error:

```
class BinaryCode {

    public:
            static int get_digit(char c)
            {
                    return (c-'0');
            }
            void decode(string decd)
            {
                    int i;

                    std::vector <int> decoded(decd.size());
                    std::transform(decd.begin(), decd.end(), decoded.begin(), &get_digit);

                    int length=decoded.size();
```

This is the topcoder problem description:

```
Definition Class:BinaryCode
Method:decode

Parameters:string
Returns:vector <string>

Method signature:
vector <string> decode(string message)
```

(be sure your method is public)

Comment: What's probably happening is that the site adds a test harness to your submitted code before it compiles it so that the site can tell whether your code is a solution to the stated problem. In this case, the test harness function `_wrapper::thunk` is expecting `BinaryCode::decode` to return a `string`.

Comment: @Insilico   Ahh yes..but it compiled on my g++. I will post the Problem Description too

Comment: Yes, but what I'm saying is that before TopCoder compiles your code it adds an extra set of functions to test your solution. Most likely the test harness is expecting your function to return something. But do please post the problem description (and a link to the problem on the TopCoder site as well).

Comment: @Insilico: SRM144 div1 300 point problem in TCHs (Practice zone)

Comment: Hang on. The method signature says you need to return a `vector<string>`. Your method signature returns nothing as a `void` method. Judging by what @insilico is saying, that would explain the error? =\

Comment: @blahman: Thanks all. YEs, i got the solution. As you said, yes it expects a vector<string> as return from decode function. That was my mistake. Thanks `In silico` and `blahman`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method signature is:

```
void decode(string decd)
```

Should be:

```
vector <string> decode(string message)
```

TopCoder compiles your code with testing code for the problem.  Make sure the code you provide meets the requirements in the problem statement.

Comment: Thanks..yes that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

Topcoder compiler is expecting the function to be

```
vector <string> decode(string message)
```

while your function is

```
void decode(string message)
```

You are using 'void' instead of vector < string >

Comment: Thanks..yes that was the problem.

Comment: Both answers are same. Upvote for you, but accepting the earlier as it was posted first.

Comment: :) We both posted at the almost the same time!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
using namespace std;
```

it fixed my problem. And also includes, it puts your code into separate file

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
```